# Convert a color image to input vector for libsvm

Tags: python, computer-vision, libsvm

I've a set of labeled training images (color). I want to use these images as input to libsvm. 
Is there is python library/function/code that can help me convert this color image into a format that libsvm will accept as input ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I have done that in python I just converted the image into an array (I always had worked on grayscale images though), something like:

```
outpath="images\\ts\\"
fp = open(outpath + 'trainingset.dump','wb');
dirList = os.listdir(path)
for fname in dirList:
if '.jpg' in fname:
    im = array(Image.open(path + "\\" + fname).convert('L'))
    pickle.dump(im,fp)
    pickle.dump(1,fp)
fp.close()
```

At the moment of passing that to libsvm you would need to turn it into a list:

```
path="images\\ts\\trainingset.dump"
fp = open(path, "r")
im = pickle.load(fp)
label = pickle.load(fp)
imlist = im.tolist()
imlist = [item for sublist in imlist for item in sublist]
y.append(label)
x.append(imlist)

print "Setting up the SVM problem"
prob = svm_problem(y, x)

param = svm_parameter('-t 2 -g 0.00001')
param.C = 1

print "Starting the training process"
m=svm_train(prob, param)

print "Storing the model"

svm_save_model(model, m)
```

Please note that although I am experienced using libsvm, I most of time used it on C++. I am new on python and that might not be the best approach, it was just the way that worked for me. Also if you would like to maintain colours you could try not converting the image to gray-scale, I haven't tried it myself but this should work, instead of:

```
im = array(Image.open(path + "\\" + fname).convert('L'))
```

use this:

```
im = array(Image.open(path + "\\" + fname))
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: can you tell me the library that has has Image ?

Comment: I think is from PIL (http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm). I left the code at home so I can double check when I get there and if it is not I will let you know